# Xamarin Binding .AAR Error : 'SecureString' does not implement interface member

Tags: xamarin

I am trying to bind a .AAR library getting the following error

CS0738  'SecureString' does not implement interface member 'ICharSequence.SubSequenceFormatted(int, int)'. 'SecureString.SubSequenceFormatted(int, int)' cannot implement 'ICharSequence.SubSequenceFormatted(int, int)' because it does not have the matching return type of 'ICharSequence'

Comment: Have you tried changing the return type of that node?

Comment: with partial class it works.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem that occurs with binding Java methods with covariant return types.
There are two ways to fix this issue:

(1).Add a partial class declaration for SecureString and explicitly implement SecureString.SubSequenceFormatted(int, int).

(2).Remove the covariance from the generated C# code.
For more information, you can refer to this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/troubleshooting-bindings